# How to Install PHPmailer on Drupal7 website

Tags: drupal-7

I tried to install PHPmailer from drupal.org/project/phpmailer, i wonder the correct location of libraries API, should it be placed in site/all? you know, if there is no libraries in site/all/module, phpmailer can't be installed successfully, at the same time, it asked user to upload libraries to site/all. I use Drupal 7.x-3.x-dev to power my personal site, your response is highly appreciated, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal7 phpmailer is already there inside the smtp module.